Angular Universal Build Error: Module Parse Failed While Creating Server Bundle
I am using Angular version 12 and have enabled server-side rendering (SSR). There is no problem when I create a regular build using ng build; it completes without any errors. However, when I run the following command for the SSR build:
"build:ssr": "ng build && ng run angular-nats-app:server",
it creates two bundles: a browser bundle and a server bundle. While there is no issue with the browser bundle, the server bundle throws an error.
./node_modules/nats.ws/esm/nats.js:7472:16 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7472:16)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         _asyncToGenerator(function* () {
|           try {
>             for await (const b of _this12.transport) {
|               _this12.parser.parse(b);
|             }


Environment 

Angular cli: ~12.0.0
Node : 14.21.3
OS : Windows 11
Package manager : npm

I tried setting the tsconfig as mentioned in the nats.ws discussion https://github.com/nats-io/nats.ws/blob/main/developer_notes.md#older-typescript-compiler. I also observe this issue with a standard build (ng build) when I change the target version to ES2017 or higher
